# Matrix Inverse as Series

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am looking for different representations of the inverse of a matrix as a power series. One obvious candidate is the Von Neumann series which is given

$$A^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (I-A)^k$$

However the series above converges only of A is Positive Definite and $\|A\| \leq 1$. Are there other series that do not explicitly require the matrix to be Positive Definite ? I am okay with the spectral norm bound as that requires only multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: Why does $A$ have to be positive definite?

Comment: In fact, the series necessarily converges **whenever** $\|A-I\| \leq 1$, for whichever matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ you want to use. Positive definite has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Also, note that for any $c>0$,
$$
A^{-1} = \frac 1c \left(\frac 1c A\right)^{-1}
$$

Comment: It is even enough that $\lVert (A - I)^n \rVert < 1$ for some $n$.

Comment: If A has even one negative eigenvalue then $\|A-I\|$ does not have spectral norm less than 1